# laravel many to many relationship not store in pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables developer table and skill table which are linked with many to many relationship developer_skill table. I want to store developer_id and skill_id is in pivot table.

but when developer add their skills and submit it return error.

on developer table data add but in pivot table data not added.
**error**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'developer_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `developer_skill` (`developer_id`, `skill_id`) values (, 5))
```

**developer controller to store data**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Developer; 
use App\Skill as skill;

class developerController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Developer $Developer, skill $skill)
    {
        $this->Developer = $Developer;
        $this->skill = $skill;
    }

     public function store(Request $request)
      {
       $skills = implode(',', $request->user_skills);
    
          $data = array(
                'name' => $request->name,
                'skills' => $skills,
            );
    
            if ($this->Developer->create($data)) {
                $syncTagData = array();
                if (!empty($request->user_skills)) {
                    $syncTagData = $request->user_skills;
                }
    
                $this->Developer->user_skills()->sync($syncTagData);
            }
}
}
```

**developer_skill**

```
developer_id
skill_id
```

**skill model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Developer::class);
}
```

**developer model**

```
public function user_skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill');

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$this->developer` in you controller? Can you show the whole method in your controller including the declaration and any constructor?

Comment: ok I am updating question

Comment: I have updated my controller

Comment: It might be helpful to see your route too. Essentially it looks like `$this->developer` is a new `Developer` not one resolved from the DB. That's why the ID is null.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised my answer was way off the mark. I had misread your code completely! I'll take another look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if ($this->Developer->create($data)) {
    $syncTagData = array();
    if (!empty($request->user_skills)) {
        $syncTagData = $request->user_skills;
    }

    $this->Developer->user_skills()->sync($syncTagData);
}
```

`$this->Developer` is already and instance of `Developer` so when you call `create()` the query it builds isn't what you might expect.

You have two options:

Use the model Facade (my preference):

```
if ($developer = Developer::create($data)) {
    $syncTagData = array();
    if (!empty($request->user_skills)) {
        $syncTagData = $request->user_skills;
    }

    $developer->user_skills()->sync($syncTagData);
}
```

Using the above, you should be able to remove your constructor as it's not needed.

Or set the properties on `$this->developer` and save:

```
$this->Developer->name = $data['name'];
$this->Developer->skills = $data['skills'];
if ($this->Developer->save()) {
    $syncTagData = array();
    if (!empty($request->user_skills)) {
        $syncTagData = $request->user_skills;
    }

    $developer->user_skills()->sync($syncTagData);
}
```

Also, be careful with your user_skills relationship name. The convention is camelCase so you might benefit from changing it to userSkills otherwise you may find odd things happening when Laravel does its magic under the hood.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Excellent! Could you mark the answer as accepted for me please? I crave the reputation points :)

Comment: I have mark it as accepted by not showing,i think my reputation is less than 15

Comment: Ah well, no worries. Glad I could help anyway